# Accessing MySQL from Python 2.7: ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000)

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-2.7

I am having difficulties connecting to a MySQL database using Python 2.7. The error I'm getting is

> ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user
>   'tommyan'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I know similar questions exist, but none of those were helpful to me. My code is below, thanks in advance.

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="127.0.0.1",
  user="tommyan",
  passwd="######",
  database="mydatabase"
)

 mycursor = mbdb.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO places (name, desc) VALUES (%s, %s)"
val = ("Natinal gallery", "Housing masterpieces by painters including van Gogh, 
Renoir, da Vinci and Michelangelo")

mycursor.execute(sql, val)

mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

Comment: Well, if its telling you plainly that you don't have the right to write to the table   or you supplied wrong username and /or password

Comment: This might be helpful: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html

Comment: Can you use the mysql shell to login to the server with those credentials?